# How to generate jacoco reports for specific module in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, code-coverage, jacoco, test-reporting

I am very new to this environment. I came from a native iOS background.

By using this https://blog.gouline.net/code-coverage-on-android-with-jacoco-92ec90c9355e, I am successfully generating the `JACOCO` test reports for my unit test class in my android project (app module only).

What I am doing is:

1. I simply create `jacoco.gradle` file in the main project.
2. Apply from: `'../jacoco.gradle'` in `app/build.gradle` file
3. Added below code in the `app/build.gradle` file

   ```
   android { 
   ... 
       buildTypes { 
           debug { 
               testCoverageEnabled = true 
            } 
           ... 
       } 
   ... 
   }
   ```
4. Open a terminal inside the Android Studio and run the command
   like

   ```
     **gradlew tasks**
   ```
5. To generate a report, run the command

   ```
   **gradlew testBlueDebugUnitTestCoverage**
   ```
6. Finally I found my reports  at this path: `\app\build\reports\tests\testTabletDebugUnitTest`

By using this http://vgaidarji.me/blog/2017/12/20/how-to-configure-jacoco-for-kotlin-and-java-project/ I have successfully generated the jacoco report for the both Espresso and Coverage test classes (UI and Unit Testing), and also this project includes both java &  kotlin classes.

Now my question is: I want to generate the `jacoco` test reports for specific module out of all other modules in my app.

**System Info:**

```
Windows 10, 
Android Studio 3.3.1, 
Kotlin: ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
Gradle:gradle:3.4.0-alpha01.
```